# Is there a way to find multiple max's and min's for segments in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have this one cylindrical machined part which has multiple grooves along the length of a straight cylinder. I scanned it along the length so I have 1000's of data points which are all the diameter of cylinder along its length.

The data looks something like this-

```
1.0  <- Starts on the flat part
.99
1.0
1.0
.95  <- Begins dipping into the groove
.93
.92  <-minimum groove depth reached
.93
.97
1.0 <- back up to flat part
1.01
1
1.01
1.0
.98  <- begins groove again 
.95
.94
.92  <- minimum groove depth reached
.93
.97
1.0  <-back to flat part
1.0
...
```

As you can see, the flat parts are all around 1 and then it dips slowly to .92 and then back up to 1 multiple times.

I am trying to find a way where it can record the max and min during the 'flat' part, then record a min for the 'groove', then record a new max and min for the new part, and so on.

The output would be something like-

Flat 1

```
Max=1.0
Min=.99
```

Groove 1

```
Min=.92
```

Flat 2

```
max=1.01
min=1.0
```

Groove 2

```
min=.92
```

And so on. Is this feasible? I have tried multiple things in excel and it's been complex and not functioning well as of now. Can this be done in Excel or do I have to use VBA? Any tips or advice would be very appreciated!

Comment: How do you differentiate between the min value in a groove and the min value in the flat part?

Comment: The min in the groove is much smaller than the flat part. So a min in the flat part will always be above .98 (otherwise there'd be visible damage to the part). The groove is much smaller (in metal machining terms at least).

Comment: Also, I'd love to get some upvotes so I can start commenting on other people's posts. I swear I'm not trying to gain fake internet points.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Assuming your data starts in cell `A2` and that you start with a "Flat"

1. In cell `B2`, type `Start Flat 1`
2. In `B3`, type the following formula:

   ```
   =IF(AND(A3>0.98,A2<=0.98),"Start Flat "&COUNTIF(B$1:B2,"Start Flat*")+1,IF(AND(A3>0.98,A4<=0.98),"End Flat "&COUNTIF(B$1:B2,"End Flat*")+1,IF(AND(A2>A3,A4>A3,A3<0.98),"Groove min. " & COUNTIFS(B$1:B2,"Groove*")+1,"")))
   ```
3. Populate down

You should get something like this:

[image]

To get a random value from the flat and the groove min:

1. Setup a table with the first column starting at `1`.
2. In the second column, insert the following formula:

   ```
   =IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,RANDBETWEEN(MATCH("Start Flat " & J2,B:B,0),MATCH("End Flat " & J2,B:B,0))),"")
   ```
3. In the third, use the following:

   ```
   =IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH("Groove min. "& J2,B:B,0)),"")
   ```

You should end up with something like this:

[image]

Comment: This is really great!! Is there any way that I could return a random value in between the flat values? The complex thing is the range is dynamic so the first flat range might be 200 data point and the second one might be 186, but I'd still want a random value from the flat zone.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. note that I made a slight change to the formula in the first table.